# a:visited not working with h:commandLink in JSF 1.2

Tags: css, jsf-1.2

We have a requirement to change the link color if the link has been used(clicked).
We are using h:commandLink with an action method. Below is a code snippet.

.xhtml file -

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="changeLinkColor" action="#{bean.actionMethod}">
        <span><h:outputText value="UserName"/></span>
        </h:commandLink>
```

.CSS file -

```
.changeLinkColor
{
 color:#0000FF;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.changeLinkColor a:link
{
 color:blue;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.changeLinkColor a:visited
{
    color: black;
}
```

Here all the styles are working properly except a:visited.
However it works fine if we change the h:commandLink to h:outputLink. But the later does not have an action method attribute. Hence can not use it.

Please share if you have any work around to get the link color changed with h:commandLink tag.

Answer (score 1):

when browser see the link address(href) was visited, change to visited color.

but commandLink will generate a link with onclick, it will return false to disable href behavior, ex:

```
<a onclick="return submitForm(x);" href="#">xx</a>
```

so this is not the JSF issue, is a html issue.

our solution is:

1. create a invisible iframe
2. override the href to a magic path
3. override the onclick function, let iframe go to the magic path first.

use jquery example:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#linkDiv a").each(function(idx, elem)) {
        elem.href = '/dummy_' + elem.innerHTML + '.xhtml';
        var oldfunc = elem.onclick;
        $(elem).click(function(){
          invisibleFrame.location.href = elem.href;
          return oldfunc();
        });
      });
    });
```